# Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones after i remove doubles

Tags: animation, bones

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33521 my link
i already search for some solution and try it but still no working.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post as an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly fixed it , First you have to select the robot then press[ <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> ] , Then select clear parent and keep transformation

Do that to the armature aswell.

Now select the robot , Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and right click the armature .

Press <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Add automatic weights.

It will now work , if you have problems just ask

Also keep in mind you will have to some manually weight distribution because it does get messy

[image]

Comment: Sry for late reply it still not working